# creating a binary vector from the dataframe column values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df`

```
    ID   KD     DT   
0    1    2     5.6  
1    1    5     8.7  
4    4    9     1.9  
5    4    2     1.7  
6    4    7     8.8  
2    6    9     8.3  
3    6    7     7.2  
9    7   36     3.1  
10   7    2     2.2  
12   7    7     5.6
```

I want to create a dataframe such that for each unique `KD` value, new columns of `{-1,0,1}` are added depending on `ID` (from a list of `ID` values) and `DT`. `ID = [1,2,4,6,7,8]`. New dataframe should have `len(ID)+1` columns with first column the unique `KD` value and `len(D)` columns such that `column ID = 1` if `df.loc[(df.ID==id) & (df.KD==kd),'DT'] >= 5`, `column ID = 0` if `(kd,id)` pair is not in `df` and `column ID = -1` if `df.loc[(df.ID==id) & (df.KD==kd),'DT'] < 5`

For the dataframe given above new dataframe should be

df2

```
    KD     1     2    4     6     7     8    

0    2     1     0    -1    0     -1    0 
1    5     1     0     0    0      0    0  
2    7     0     0     1    1      1    0
3    9     0     0    -1    1      0    0
4   36     0     0     0    0     -1    0
```

In fact, number of unique `KD` and `ID` are very large (in the range of 10K). Any help in finding a very efficient way to do this. please ?

Comment: Is your row 3 column 4 correct?    KD=9  and ID=4 with DT value of 1.9 which is less than 5, shouldn't  be -1?

Comment: @ScottBoston spot on :-). Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this using `pivot` and `mask`:

```
ID = [1,2,4,6,7,8]
df_p = df.pivot('KD', 'ID', 'DT')
df_p.mask((df_p >= 5), 1).mask(df_p < 5, -1).reindex(ID, axis=1)\
    .fillna(0).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
ID  KD    1    2    4    6    7    8
0    2  1.0  0.0 -1.0  0.0 -1.0  0.0
1    5  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2    7  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
3    9  0.0  0.0 -1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
4   36  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 -1.0  0.0
```